# Const reference to lambda causes use-after-scope?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, address-sanitizer

MSVC Asan reports a use-after-scope error which I can't understand.

Example code boils down to

```
int main() {
    std::list<std::string> listOfStr;
    const auto& pred = [](const std::string& str) { return true; };
    const auto result = std::find_if(listOfStr.cbegin(), listOfStr.cend(), pred);

    return 0;
}
```

being compiled using MSVC 2019 compiler with the following options:

```
cl main.cpp /fsanitize=address /Zi /std:c++17
```

I won't copy here the complete error text, but I figured out that asan alerts on `std::find_if` call before reaching the first line of `find_if`'s implementation.

If we remove debug info (`/Zi`) or switch to pre-c++17 standard (remove `/std:c++17`), the error is gone.

What's the reason? Is it a bug in asan, or there is something new about references in c++17?

Comment: I suspect it's the const reference to lambda. This bug in sanitizer was also present in gcc, but was fixed.

Comment: The code looks OK to me, for what it's worth. Looks like a false positive. That said, it's kinda pointless to store the lambda by const reference; `find_if` takes it by value anyway.